# Running update query for two input field even if the one input field is sent blank

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to build a admin panel for a website, In  that admin panel I have a section to update the title and subtitle of the page. I created a form with new Title and Subtile input fields with single update button(both fields are marked "not required"). Now if only 1 field is filled it updates the database , if no field is filled then I am returning user to same page both these function are working as intended.

Now the main issue is when both field are filled then only one field is getting updated in the database. I have used If statements but I am not able to figure out how to make it work.

So first I created 3 If{} blocks, 1st one checks if both field are empty, 2nd check if title field is filled , 3rd if subtiltle field is filled. I also tried it with if else statement. Below is my form and php code.

PHP CODE TO UPDATE

```
<?php
    require('header.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        
        $ptitle_id=1;
        $new_title = $_POST['title'];
        $new_subtitle = $_POST['subtitle'];

        if (empty($_POST['title']) &&  empty($_POST['subtitle'])) {
            echo "<script>window.location.href='workflow_title.php'</script>";
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['title'])) {
            $sql="UPDATE `project_title` SET `title` = ? WHERE `ptitle_id`= ?";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param('si',$new_title,$ptitle_id);
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['subtitle'])) {
            $sql="UPDATE `project_title` SET `subtitle`= ? WHERE `ptitle_id`= ?";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param('si',$new_subtitle,$ptitle_id);            
        }
        
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        echo "<script>window.location.href='workflow_title.php'</script>";
    }

?>
```

HTML CODE FORM

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="card card-primary">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h4 class="card-title">New links</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>New Title</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control tb-textarea" name="title" rows="2"
                                placeholder="Enter new title..."></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>New Subtitle</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control tb-textarea" name="subtitle" rows="2"
                                placeholder="Enter new subtitle.."></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Build the update statement gradually instead of overwriting it

Comment: @ADyson thanks for reply but can you please elaborate.

Comment: Make one update statement string, and add the right bits to the SET statement depending which fields were submitted.

Comment: @ADyson Okk you mean something like this.... $sql = UPDATE table set ....then in the first if statement " $sql .= column name = ? where id  = ? ". Am I right?

Comment: Exactly that, yes

Comment: @ADyson Thankyou so much for helping me to improve the code, also I found the solution to my issue bye moving execute statement inside the if blocks,